# How to remove seconds and milliseconds from mobile view of lightning-input time type

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobile, time

Is there a way to remove or hide seconds and milliseconds from lightning-input time type (on mobile android device)?
[image: mobile lightning-input time type]

Comment: I believe your only option would be to write your own; the standard component just calls whatever the OS does by default. That said, there could possibly be some kind of attribute you can set, but I couldn't find anything on that.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem